# operator << for internal class of a template class

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I want to implement `operator <<` that would print contents of internal class of a template class, i.e. `X<T>::Y`. It is okay to add any `friend` declarations needed. How to do it?

Here is a full example of what I want to compile in C++11:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
class X {
public:
    X(T d): y(d) {}

private:
    class Y {
    public:
        Y(T d): data(d) {}

    private:
        T data;

        template <typename U>
        friend std::ostream &operator <<(std::ostream &os, const typename X<U>::Y &y);
    };

    Y y;

    template <typename U>
    friend std::ostream &operator <<(std::ostream &os, const X<U> &x);
};

// This operator is not detected by the operator below
template <typename U>
std::ostream &operator <<(std::ostream &os, const typename X<U>::Y &y) {
    os << "Y(" << y.data << ")";
    return os;
}

template <typename U>
std::ostream &operator <<(std::ostream &os, const X<U> &x) {
    os << "X " << x.y;
    return os;
}

int main() {
    std::cout << X<int>(1);
    return 0;
}
```

The compiler error I get is:

```
error: no match for 'operator<<' (operand types are 'std::basic_ostream<char>' and 'const X<int>::Y')
 os << "X " << x.y;
            ^
```

Comment: The `U` in `typename X<U>::Y` is in a non-deduced context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This doesn't work since `typename X<U>::Y` is a dependent type. If you want to print e.g. an `int`, should the compiler just test all possible types for `U` (there are infinite many due to recursion) in order to check, whether `typename X<U>::Y` results as an `int` (consider template specialisation!)? Therefore the only possibility is to implement the function right at the friend statement:

```
class Y {
public:
    Y(T d): data(d) {}

private:
    T data;

    friend std::ostream &operator <<(std::ostream &os, Y const& y)
    {
        os << "Y(" << y.data << ")";
        return os;
    }
};
```

http://ideone.com/dx8Qri

Comment: It works. Why can't compiler just use unification to match from all defined `operator <<` though?

Comment: I don't understand what you're meaning with *unification*. In this case, it might be technically possible to deduce `U` in `const typename X<U>::Y &` from `X<int>::Y`, but that's not always the case due to (partial) template specialisation. How should the compiler behave in the following case? http://ideone.com/ErCffh